# MongoDB Aggregation for every element of array field of a document

Tags: mongodb, join, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections -

Student collection (sample student document)

```
{
'id': '123',
'name': 'john',
'age': 25,
'fav_colors': ['red', 'black'],
'marks_in_subjects': [
    {
     'marks': 90,
     'subject_id': 'abc'
    },
    {
     'marks': 92,
     'subject_id': 'def'
    }
 ]
}
```

Subjects collection (2 sample documents)

```
{
'id': 'abc',
'name': 'math'
},
{
'id': 'def',
'name': 'physics'
}
```

When I query for student document for id: '123', I want the resulting output as:

```
{
'id': '123',
'name': 'john',
'age': 25,
'fav_colors': ['red', 'black'],
'marks_in_subjects': [
    {
     'marks': 90,
     'subject_id': 'abc',
     'subject_name': 'math'
    },
    {
     'marks': 92,
     'subject_id': 'def',
     'subject_name': 'physics'
    }
 ]
}
```

Now, I read the MongoDB aggregation pipelines and operators document, still, I am clueless as to how to achieve this. The doubt persists because I am not even sure if this is possible with the help of mongo aggregation pipelines since JOIN happens here for every element of the array field in the student document.

It would be really helpful if anyone can help here. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `$match` you conditions
- `$unwind` deconstruct `marks_in_subjects` array
- `$lookup` with `subjects` collection
- `$addFields` to get first element `name` from return subject
- `$group` by `id` and reconstruct `marks_in_subjects` array and also add your required field of root document using `$first` operator

```
db.students.aggregate([
  { $match: { id: "123" } },
  { $unwind: "$marks_in_subjects" },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "subjects",
      localField: "marks_in_subjects.subject_id",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "marks_in_subjects.subject_name"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      "marks_in_subjects.subject_name": {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$marks_in_subjects.subject_name.name", 0]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id",
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      age: { $first: "$age" },
      fav_colors: { $first: "$fav_colors" },
      marks_in_subjects: { $push: "$marks_in_subjects" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ny5NiRRS2yz)

---

Second option without `$unwind` stage,

- `$match` you conditions
- `$lookup` with `subjects` collection
- `$addFields` to get subject name from `subjects`

  - `$map` to iterate loop of `marks_in_subjects` array
  - `$reduce` to iterate loop of `subjects` array and check condition if `subject_id` match then return subject `name`
  - `$mergeObjects` to merge current object of `marks_in_subjects` and new field `subject_name`
- `$unset` to remove `subjects` array because its not needed now

```
db.students.aggregate([
  { $match: { id: "123" } },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "subjects",
      localField: "marks_in_subjects.subject_id",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "subjects"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      marks_in_subjects: {
        $map: {
          input: "$marks_in_subjects",
          as: "m",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$m",
              {
                subject_name: {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: "$subjects",
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: {
                      $cond: [{ $eq: ["$$this.id", "$$m.subject_id"]}, "$$this.name", "$$value"]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unset: "subjects" }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gj8dfBEIinX)

Comment: Hey @turivishal- Thanks buddy. It worked. Thanks a lot. However, I have one more doubt. Suppose there is name field also in the students collection, how can I get name field in the output document as well? I know there is one solution to push name field in the group stage of pipeline. However that sets name field as an array. How can I add name field in the output as the key value field?

Comment: you just need only name field or other fields required?

Comment: I mean I want every other field in the original document to remain in the final resulting document. So if the original students document has n other fields, I want them to persist in the final resulting document after adding subjects name in the marks in subject field. I hope I was clear. Thanks again for giving time to this.

Comment: can you just show your expected result, just change result from playground and share here.

Comment: @turivishal- I have updated the input and output in the question details :)

Comment: updated first solution and also added second option of query.

Comment: @turivishal - Thanks a lot. Your updated solution worked. I think it made me understand the aggregation pipeline more clearly after this. Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/H5fHpfWz5VH

```
db.Students.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$marks_in_subjects" //  break into individual documents
  },
  {
    "$lookup": { // get subject details
      "from": "Subjects",
      "localField": "marks_in_subjects.subject_id",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "subjects"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: { // set name
      "marks_in_subjects.name": "subjects.0.name" // pick value from 0 index
    }
  },
  {
    $group: { // join document back by id
      _id: "$_id",
      marks_in_subjects: { $push: "$marks_in_subjects" }
    }
  }
])
```